# Why does the "white" part of an image turn "black" after saving?

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop

I've noticed that sometimes when we save an image and open it with Adobe Photoshop, the "white" background turns "black".

For example, when I view [this image](https://calendar.google.com/googlecalendar/images/combined_v37_vr.png) using Chrome, this is what I see:

[image]

However, when I saved the file to my computer (*"right-click" → "Save image as.."*) then open the file with Photoshop CS5, this is what I see:

[image]

Why does the "white" part of an image turn "black" after saving?

Comment: Has it actually turned "black", or is that just the background colour shown for transparent areas?

Comment: @lakovosian It turned black. If it was transparent, photoshop would display the "white-gray" checker boxes: http://screenshoot.me/vLd21c

Comment: I'm not sure why that happened for you in Photoshop, but the original image you linked to definitely has a transparent background. Perhaps there is another underlying problem still to identify?

Comment: @lakovosian Yes, the point of this post is to identify the underlying problem.

Comment: Have you tried using the *background eraser* on the black area to see if it is actually treated as transparent?

Comment: @lakovosian When I "erased" the "black" area, it turns "white-gray": http://screenshoot.me/rx6jQI. So I guess it means that the "black" area was really "black" and not "transparent".

Comment: are you saving the image as a **"JPG"**? If so try saving it to **"PNG"**.

Comment: @X no I'm saving it as PNG

Answer (score 7):

This issue occurs when copying images with transparency. The part you're referring to as white (that turns black) isn't really white, it's transparent.

When you copy a `*.png` image, what you technically do is save it in your clipboard; but there's a problem: your clipboard is only capable of storing `*.bmp` images. So the system converts the `*.png` image to a `*.bmp` before storing it at your clipboard. Now here's your problem: `*.bmp` does *not* support alpha channels (transparency). So what happens to the transparent pixels? they become black.

So the most straightforward solution is to just not use your clipboard (**tl;dr**): Save the image to a file, and open the file in Photoshop.

Comment: But I did saved the file to my computer and opened it directly with Photoshop as a file. It is still showing "black" instead of "transparent".

Comment: @Pacerier Sounds like the issue is with Photoshop. which version are you running?

Comment: The version I'm using is CS5

Comment: @Pacerier Sounds very odd. I've opened it at Photoshop CS6 (which isn't very different) and it opens up perfectly. try to look at the settings etc. maybe the answer is there. I'll try to look up what could be the issue and if I find anything, I'll get back to you. Good luck.

Comment: did you manage to find the issue?

Comment: @Pacerier I haven't found any reason when you've asked the question but I'm willing to give it another go. Is it like that with every `.png` file?

Comment: nop other files like http://images.wikia.com/bloodbrothersgame/images/6/63/Oniroku_The_Unhinged_Raid_Boss.png and http://freelogoplanet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Caduceus-Logo.png open up just fine. It's just this particular image that has it's background turned from transparent to black.

Comment: @Pacerier Well then it's not in the settings. I'm not sure what is causing this behavior (I'm not very technical with Photoshop) but I opened your file in Photoshop, saved it as .psd so you could work on it properly. Here is the link (MediaFire scanned it with BitDefender, in case you're worried about security) http://www.mediafire.com/?sv7b78otdv4aau8 . I hope it could satisfy you even tho it's not much of a solution.

Comment: Thanks MasterMastic, your suggestion worked for me. Save to computer and then add to photoshop instead of dragging image from browser into photoshop ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's because it has transparency. And different applications may have different default background colors. In Firefox your picture is shown with a dark gray background.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Comment: But why is it that instead of showing it as "transparent" (http://screenshoot.me/vLd21c), photoshop shows it as "black"?

Comment: Perhaps it's a problem with your layer, I don't have Photoshop to make some tests.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't edit the layers at all. I directly opened the saved file with Photoshop and it is showing "black" instead of "transparent" (which it should have).

Comment: stop upvoting this answer, it isn't answering the question...

Comment: Yes, it is... (>'-')> mhm... Even Kirby agrees.

Comment: ....What Kirby?

Comment: <('-')> <--- Kirby. http://kirby.nintendo.com/

Comment: You should delete this answer. It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I'll delete my answer when you'll delete your account. Everyone is telling you it's about transparency, you still think it's some kind of voodoo magic. Why the heck don't you ask the Adobe support team about your problem?

Answer (score 3):

This [issue appears](http://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/opening_transparent_png_loses_transparency) when a PNG is saved with indexed color in CS5 and below.

Photoshop cannot properly display PNG files that have indexed color for transparency because of the way the transparency data is embedded in the alpha palette versus being stored in a separate alpha mask.

The result is Photoshop reading the RGB components of each indexed color and ignoring the the transparency data embedded in the alpha palette of the image. In a normally-saved PNG, this data would be included in a separate alpha mask and be read appropriately by the program. In this case, with the transparency data unable to be read, the image background turns black.

You can read more about this here: [Why can't Photoshop properly open this PNG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/why-cant-photoshop-properly-open-this-png)

Later versions of Photoshop are able to display indexed color PNGs with their intended transparency.

Answer (score 2):

Yep - the linked picture definitely has a transparent background. Confirmed with GIMP as shown below.

[image: Transparency with GIMP]

---

As for why your transparent background looks black in PhotoShop may be linked to this:
[Chose background colour in PhotoShop](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110221001551AAEUiJK) <-- Hopefully will lead you in the right direction.
I think you just need to change the *Application Background* colour back to transparent instead of black.

Comment: That link is only applicable for "creating new images". As I described in the post, I directly saved the file to desktop as a .png file, so I didn't create any new file. In other words, I didn't modify the background in anyway, it should have been still "transparent". Yet photoshop is showing it as "black".

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, it's a matter of the PNG using indexed color for transparency... something Photoshop doesn't like to handle.

More on it at [the Graphic Design StackExchange.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5888/why-cant-photoshop-properly-open-this-png)

Answer (score 2):

I opened my image with "Paint" and then I saved it as a .bmp and it had a message that popped up saying "by saving this image you will lose your transparency".  When I saved it, the background turned white!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, transparent backgrounds print from CPS black. Before I print from CPS I set the background layer WHITE, then print - even for png's. When I save the picture, I turn off the background layer and save as png. Then when its displayed in a website or whatever, the background is transparent. Work with the background layer and its a simple fix. Though, Corel should allow for transparent printing.

Answer (score 0):

Photo Gallery saves the transparency of png images with a black background. Paint saves them as a white background.